Error adding user: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
i try to use the signup, but the error keep coming in Error adding user:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
    at signup (D:\feesightcloud revisi\controllers\authController.js:25:21)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

which is
displayName,
passwordHash: hashedPassword
};
await firestore.collection('users').doc(userRecord.uid).set(userData);

all the firebases is imported succesfully both in api.js and firebase.js
i tried used postman, it does store in the authentication but didnt get to users collection

Looks like firestore might be undefined.  We can't see if or how you assigned it, so there's not much we can do without all that additional context.  Please edit the question to provide a complete minimal reproducible example of code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.
